# Python Fullstack Application - python manage.py runserver - No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, local, react-fullstack

I have followed [this tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZgRbnIsgrA).

First, I think everything was fine etc. but when I want so run the Server with: python manage.py runserver it doesn't work. I got the following error:

```
bash: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

The manage.py file is there and I have tried it several times. I don't know what the problem can be. I have reinstalled python, home-brew, pip and virtualenv

Comment: Did you install Python on your system?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have Python installed, or it isn't present in your PATH variables.

In command line try the following

```
python --version
```

You should expect to see

```
python x.x.x
```

If it isn't included in your PATH variables, you will receive

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This can be fixed by going to the following

1. Right click `This PC` and select `Advanced Properties`
2. Click `Environment Variables` and select `Path` from the `System variables`
3. Click `Edit` and add Python. It should be at `C:\PythonXX`, though it would depend on your install directory

And adding Python

---

**If Python is already installed**

If Python is already installed, you aren't in the correct working directory. Could you please share your directory tree, including where manage.py is located.

Comment: First, thank you. When I type python --version it although says the same thing: -bash: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/python: No such file or directory.  But I installed python with home-brew. How to install correctly? my working directory is the same as in the youtube video.

Comment: It sounds like it's not added in your PATH then. If you were to open Python.exe an try `python --version` it will work. I've edited the first portion of my answer to explain this better for you.

Comment: OK thank you. I work on Mac, so do you maybe although have a explanation for my os? I am desperate :(

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry.